# R: return one TRUE / FALSE from a group of boolean values

Tags: r

Suppose:

```
mu.iter <- c(3,3,3,3)
mu <- c(1,4,1,4)

> abs(mu.iter - mu) > 1.5
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Instead of four TRUE/FALSE values, I just want one TRUE / FALSE value, such that it only returns TRUE when all 4 are TRUE and FALSE otherwise. The reason is that I want to put this into a while-loop.

Comment: And you might want to reconsider using a `while` loop. It's very rare that it's really needed and there are often much better alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `all`:

```
all(abs(mu.iter - mu) > 1.5)
```

Comment: … and the complement function, `any`, if you need 1+ `TRUE` statements.